# While opening the file getting OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/uprobe_events' error

Tags: python, linux-kernel

Below python script is used to write data in to file

```
fileHandler = open("/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/uprobe_events", "w")
fileHandler.write("1")
fileHandler.close()
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "File_Operation.py", line 4, in <module>
fileHandler = open("/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/uprobe_events", "w")
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/uprobe_events'
```

Comment: I think this file is already opened by another process. Why would you write in a kernel debug tracing log?

Comment: In order to run some few test cases related to kernel uprobes

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Unfortunately, it is a general error and without a context it is difficult to understand why it happened.

I've looked for solutions, but nothing very useful. You can have a look here, maybe your problem is related to another in this thread:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-embedded-and-single-board-computer-78/what-is-error-ioerror-%5Berrno-16%5D-device-or-resource-busy-4175599788/

Comment: Thank you for above information. The issue is fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).